# handling aborted http requests - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the resolved promise object after aborting a REST call (using {timeout: canceller.promise}), but I'm unable to get the resolved promise object.

factory:

```
angular.module('RestModule').factory('abc', function ($http, $rootScope) {
    var canceller = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.$on('CANCEL_REQUESTS', function () {
        canceller.resolve({'isAborted': true});
    });
    return {
        getDetails: function() {
            return $http.get('/test/testREST', {timeout: canceller.promise}).then(function (data) {
                return httpData.data;
            });
        }
});
```

controller:

```
.controller('testCtrl', function (abc, $rootScope) {
    abc.getDetails().then(function (data) {
        // success call back
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error.isAborted);
    });
    $rootScope.$emit('CANCEL_REQUESTS');
});
```

Here in the error call back I'm not getting the timeout promise object (isAborted: true). error.isAborted is undefined.

Comment: shouldn't you call `canceller.reject` instead of `canceller.resolve`, if you're expecting that result in the error handler function?

Comment: I did that initially but it never came to the error handler in that case. Only if I resolve control is reaching the error handler.

Also using canceller.resolve still reaches the error handler

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 promises in your snippet:

```
var P1 = var canceller = $q.defer();
var P2 = $http.get(...)..
```

If you resolve P1 with the value V1, you should expect P1 *then* callbacks to be called with V1, but not P2 ones.

You should handle cancellation code via the canceller promise (P1):

```
canceller.promise.then(function(data){
    console.log(data.isAborted);
});
```

I guess you are expecting Angular to wire up the handler of the **timeout *resolve*** promise with the handler of the **$http.get *reject*** promise, which I don't think is specified.

Also you might want to reset *canceller* somewhere in your code, otherwise if you call getDetails() and cancel it , *cancelled* will be resolved, so the next time your call getDetails(), *cancelled* will still be in the resolved state, and if you try to cancel it, nothing is likely to happen, as promises are resolved only once.

Answer (score 0):

My response gets a config.timeout.$$state object that stores the resolve parameter in `value`.

```
.controller('testCtrl', function (abc, $rootScope) {
    abc.getDetails().then(function (data) {
        // success call back
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error.config.timeout.$$state.value.isAborted);
    });
    $rootScope.$emit('CANCEL_REQUESTS');
});
```